# How to transition item size change inside a display: flex; justify-content: space-between; div

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` container div with 2 chidren inside. The second child classes will be changed to include (or not) a class with `display: none;`. It does get hidden when the logic applies this class, and the first child grows in width to fit the parent div. The problem is that I can't make the first child width change to transition, so when the second child goes hidden or not, the first child is instantly changing its width. I want its width to grow to its full width, instead of suddenly changing to its full width.

I am using React, but it should be possible only with css, right? If so, how can I achieve this?

Here is the reproducible example:

```js
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click",function(e){
    document.getElementById("second").classList.toggle("hidden")
},false);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  background: #aaf;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
}

.container > *:first-child {
  background: #afa;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container > *:last-child {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  background: #faa;
  width: 50px;
}

.container > *:last-child.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><span>1st</span></div>
  <div id="second" class="hidden">2nd</div>
</div>
<button id="toggle">toggle</button>
```

Comment: "I can't make the first child width change to transition" Can you clarify this? Do you want the 1st element to remain a certain size when you toggle?

Comment: I want its calculated width to transition between its initial size and its size when the second child becomes hidden and vice versa. So when the second child becomes hidden, it should grow to its full width instead of suddenly change to its full width.

Comment: Pleae read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. A link to a codepen alon is neither acceptable nor allowed according the guidelines. You even where warned about this while trying to post this question. Questions must be self-containing and not relay on external resources that might change, getting removed or be unavailable in other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to transition between widths, you must toggle the width value and use the CSS transition property. You cannot transition the width using `hidden`, as this is either true or false, there are no intermediate values to transition between.

Changes I made to your code:

- Add overflow: hidden on the container
- Toggle between widths (instead of the 'hidden' property). This enables transition to work.
- Add `transition: width 2s` to both children.

```js
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click",function(e){
 
  const width = document.getElementById("second").style.width;

if (width === "" || width === "50px") {
  document.getElementById("second").style.width = "0px";
} else {
  document.getElementById("second").style.width = "50px";
}

},false);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  background: #aaf;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container > *:first-child {  
  background: #afa;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 2s;
}

.container > *:last-child {  
  background: #faa;
  width: 50px;
  transition: width 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><span>1st</span></div>
  <div id="second">2nd</div>
</div>
<button id="toggle">toggle</button>
```